# add object in an array of objects (objects are multimensional)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, push

How can i add two objects (myobject1 and myobject2) in an Array of objects (myArray)?

`myArray.push(myobject1)` doesn't work.

```
var myArray=  [{value:[1,2,3],label:red},{value:[1,2,3],label:blue},{value:[1,2,3],label:yellow}];

var myobject1={type: 'spline',name: 'Moyenne',data: moyenneArray,marker: {lineWidth: 2,lineColor: getOptions().colors[3],fillColor: 'white'}};

var myobject2= {type: 'pie',name: 'Total entreprise',data: seriesTotal,center: [100, 30],size: 100,showInLegend: false,dataLabels: {enabled: false}};};
```

Comment: Post your full code, so we can help accurately.

Comment: I don't think you can have a function in an array. The getOptions().colors will cause the push to not work.

Comment: @AllanF.Gagnon — You can have a function in an array, but that syntax will put the value of the colors property of the return value of calling the getOptions function in the array … which probably isn't a function.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this

```
myArray.push(myobject1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push them both you could always concat
    myArray.concat([myObject1,myObject2])